# Make a monolithic architecture into something modular

Tags: architecture, coupling

Currently my architecture is a monolithic block that handles a really specific duty. Now it needs to be generalized.

Right now it handles a request and all processes (1 or many) associated to it. There's a class `Request` and a class `Process` and since it serves one specific duty this model was OK.

Right now I need to split both classes to achieve modularity. For instance, the `Request` class should be split. So I'll still have a `Request` class, which holds general request information, and many `RequestDetailsForServiceOne`, `RequestDetailsForServiceTwo` and so on, that hold detailed information relatively to a specific type of request. Equally for `Process`.

*The question right now is: how to bind together `Request` class with `RequestDetailsForServiceOne` (at run time)?*

I had thought about Dependency Injection, but `RequestDetailsForServiceOne` and `RequestDetailsForServiceTwo` doesn't share any common behaviour, (that classes only store some properties), this way will drive me to code an `IRequestDetailsForService` completely empty. That sounds as a code-smell to me.

Would be a better idea in this case use, (inside `Request`/`Process` class) a Dictionary of properties and completely avoid `RequestDetailsForService*` classes? 
I don't really like the loss of type-checking that this way get me back. What would be an ideal solution?

Comment: why Dependency Injection? What you are describing looks like a classical inheritance pattern. RequestDetailsForServiceOne is-a Request and RequestDetailsForServiceTwo is-a Request..

Comment: I wouldn't use inheritance.

Comment: @marianoc84: why not? as VP says, this sounds like a the kind of problem inheritance solves.

Comment: Because it will be a nightmare when the system will grow.

Comment: IMO there is no difference in maintaining code with dependency injection or inheritance. Why you think that DI is better?  As you described, you should use inheritance.

Comment: In practice the right answer depends on the differences and similarities between ServiceOne, ServiceTwo, their requests, any future services, and _their_ requests. There's not enough information to recommend one design over another (although you should get over whatever issue you have with inheritance, which is at least sometimes a good solution).

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two approaches that can compliment each other, but they have different mechanisms.

### Step 1: Define what success looks like

Before you begin, you have to define the target architecture.  Are you just creating modules in a monolithic application, or are you actually breaking that apart into microservices?

- Define what modules/services you need
- Define any qualitative requirements you have (i.e. must process X requests/second)
- Clarify authorization responsibilities

There's obviously more things to consider, but these will get you thinking in the right direction.

### Strategy: Strangler Method

The Strangler method basically has you build the new thing you are migrating to, and then have your legacy code start using that instead of the legacy code.

### Strategy: Mikado Method

Named for the book I learned it from, is an approach to discovering what the steps are to get from anarchy to order.  It embraces version control as an enabler, and has you rolling back or abandoning branches when you get stuck.

The general approach works like this:

1. Decide on the refactoring you want.
2. Attempt the refactoring on a new branch
3. If successful, merge your changes
4. If the changes become too pervasive or difficult, identify the blocker and add that as a pre-requisite step

   1. Abandon the failed branch (delete it)
   2. Start over with the new step first.

You very well may need to do this when factoring out the legacy code that is replaced by the new thing you created in the Strangler Method.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it modular with an "encapsulation" approach instead of "inheritance".

Only the process needs the specifics, so it should be de-serializing the specifics there.

So you should have a `Request` as usual, but then a `ProcessSpecificData` string (or byte[]) field.

This completely decouples your processes from the Request Handler module.

---

It MAY be even better to have the processes deserialise "all" of the data. That would further decouple the processes. The Request Handler would deserialize enough to route to the correct process, but then it would simply pass that process a single string (or byte[] array).

With this level, it will be possible for a Process to run directly on its own, which would be nice for testing.